# put route not working in node.js

Tags: node.js, routes

I have a problem with my PUT route, but i do not know exactly what.

First I created my schema:

```
var databaseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        date: type {
           type: Date,
        {
        _id: String,
    });

var Db = mongoose.model('Db', databaseSchema);
```

After I created a post method:

```
app.post('/db', function(req, res) {
        var body = req.body,
            database = new Db(body);
        database.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('err', err);
                res.status(500).json(err);
                return;
            }
            res.status(200).json('ok');
            console.log('Success');
```

In my INDEX, I created a GET with Ajax, to display the data in HTML:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: host + '/db',
   success:function(datas){

datas.forEach (function (data) {
        var HTML = [];

        HTML.push('<tr class="datas">');
        HTML.push('<td data-id="' + data._id + '"/> </td>');
        HTML.push('</tr>');

        $('tbody').append(HTML.join(''));
```

I created a date in my index, and I'm trying to send it along with the ID to my database, for this I use the PUT method, like this:

```
                           $.ajax({
                                type: 'PUT',
                                url: host + '/db',
                                data: {
                                    _id: update.attr('data-id'),
                                    date: $('.date').val();
                                },
                                sucess:function (success) {
                                    alert('ok');
                                },
                                error:function(err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                }
                            });
```

Finally I update her on my app.put route, like this:

```
app.put('/db', function(req, res) {
    Reserva.findById(req.param('date'), function(err, database){
        database.save(function (req, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('err', err);
            }
            res.status(200).json('ok');
            console.log('Update');
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is that the put is not working and I'm not finding the error, could someone give me a light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many browsers (even modern) don't support any request methods beyond `GET` and `POST`. To get these to work, you must do a few things:

Express app:

1. Install the `method-override` package.
2. Require it in your app: `var methodOverride = require('method-override');`
3. Add it in the middleware: `app.use(methodOverride('_method'));`

Client-side JS:
Modify your AJAX call to include the `_method` field in your data.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST', // Change this to a method everyone understands
  url: host + '/db',
  data: {
      _id: update.attr('data-id'),
      date: $('.date').val(), // <- Remove the semicolon that was here
      _method: 'PUT'
  },
  // ...
});
```

Comment: TY Sam!! You seem to understand much more than I. could you answer one more question please?

Comment: In my app.put, this part ' Reserva.findById(req.param('date'), function(err, database){' it's right?

Comment: I think you might want to revise that a little. `findById()` will find a single record by the primary key, the date, I am guessing, is not. You might want to try `Reserva.find({date: req.param('date')}, ... );`, but editing the `date` key in the query to the matching field that carries the date data you want to match.